# Filtering multiple meta_values

Tags: post-meta

I'm trying to create a filter using two meta_values.

Example.
If the current page has meta values red and blue, only display queried pages that have both red and blue and none that have just red or just blue.

I thought this could be accomplished with two meta values `'meta_value' => $red, $blue` but apparently it's not available. Below is where I found myself before the block. I've done a ton of research and simply can't find a method that works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$red = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'red', true);
$blue = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'blue', true);
$args = array(
'post_type' => page,
'nopaging' => true,
'post_parent' => 1440,
'meta_value' => $red, $blue
);

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: I now see that this is a WordPress 3.1 feature. Is there currently a way to "fake" it.

Comment: are you asking about two different custom fields? or one field with multiple values?

Comment: Two different Custom fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'meta_query' is what you're looking for:

http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work if you wrap it in an array? Not entirely sure, though ... 'meta_value' => array('red', 'blue').